# Generating lines

Tags: geometry, 3d

Show that the generators of the hyperboloid $\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}–\frac{z^2}{4}=1$ which are parallel to the plane $4x-5y-10z + 7 = 0$ are $x+5=0, y+2z=0$ and $y+4=0, 2x=5z$

My attempt

Equation of generators of $\mu$ system of the given hyperboloid is
$$(\frac X5+\frac z2)= \mu(1+\frac y4), (\frac x5–\frac z2)=(\frac1\mu)(1-\frac y4)$$
This generator will be parallel to the given plane if $\frac{\frac 15}4 = \frac{-\frac\mu4}{–5} = \frac{\frac 12}{–10} = (\frac{-\mu}7) = k$ (say).

This implies that $1=20k$ and $-1=20k$ implies that $k=0$

Therefore $\mu=0$

Therefore $\frac x5+\frac z2=0,y=4$

But this is not the answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where did these canned formulas come from? You’re presumably using some shortcut I do not know and cannot decipher here.

Comment: The equations of the generator lines are exact. Your errors are the line after : 1) you are expressing a kind of parallelism with the **normal vector** (4,-5,-10) to the plane 2) You use only one of the two equations of the generator lines.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin These "canned formulas" are a "not unusual" way to obtain one of the two families of generating lines of a one-sheeted hyperboloid. See my answer where I point to the fact that there is another family.

Comment: @JeanMarie I am quite familiar with doubly-ruled surfaces, but have never before seen this shortcut. Presumably this approach was well known in the 19th century, but it was missing in my education.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Indeed it is in old books too that I have seen them for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your equations :

$$\begin{cases}(\frac x5+\frac z2)&=&\mu(1+\frac y4)\\(\frac x5–\frac z2)&=&(\frac1\mu)(1-\frac y4)\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

Indeed their product gives back the equation of the hyperboloid. But you must be conscious that (1) describes only one of the two families of generating lines, the other one being :

$$\begin{cases}(\frac y4+\frac z2)&=& \lambda(1+\frac x5)\\(\frac y4–\frac z2)&=&(\frac1\lambda)(1-\frac x5)\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

The main result we must know for solving your problem is that a directing vector of a line defined in this way (i.e., as the intersection of 2 planes):

$$\begin{cases}ax+by+cz&=&d\\a'x+b'y+c'z&=&d'\end{cases} \ \text{is given by cross product} \ \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}a'\\b'\\c'\end{pmatrix}$$

In our case, we will have:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1/5\\-\mu/4\\1/2\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}1/5\\1/(4 \mu)\\-1/2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\mu/8-1/(8 \mu)\\1/5\\1/(20 \mu)+\mu/20\end{pmatrix}$$

This vector must be orthogonal to the normal vector to the plane, a fact that we express as a dot product equal to $0$:

$$\color{red}{4}[\mu/8-1/(8 \mu)]+\color{red}{(-5)}(1/5)+\color{red}{(-10)}[1/(20 \mu)+\mu/20]=0$$

This equation will give a single value $\mu=-1$.

Inserting this value of $\mu$ into (1) gives :

$$\begin{cases}\frac x5+\frac z2+1+\frac y4&=&0\\\frac x5-\frac z2+1-\frac y4&=&0\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

This system of equations doesn't look to be any of the given ones. **But** by adding and subtracting equations (3), we obtain the *equivalent* system :

$$\begin{cases}x+5&=&0\\y+2z&=&0\end{cases}$$

which is one of the two equations that were given to you.

Where has the second one been "lost" ? Nowhere, we must just consider the other family described by (2) and do the same kind of (a little tedious) calculations.